# Not able to create database in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to create database in phpMyAdmin. I have done these many times before in my old system and old phpMyAdmin version, but currently not able to do it. And tried to search this problem through a lot of question,but couldn't find the answers.

Because Most of them have problem of privilege, but i think i don't have this problem because i have all the privileges.

When i am trying to create database, it doesn't give any error but it just displays "Processing Request".

I am attaching screenshot.
[image]

let me know if you can think of any reason behind this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do your network tools say (Chrome Developer Tools) about the request?

Comment: Instead of using Php MyAdmin did you try using the basic MySQL client shipped, on the same machine?

Comment: @Paulpro : i don't understand what are you saying ?

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj : No i haven't tried it.

Comment: Then you should try that too... It should give some proper error code, iff you are able to login successfully into DB

Comment: I was able to create database by writing sql, but when i tried to open it from left bar. it gives me this error "The requested URL /phpMyAdmin/db_structure.php was not found on this server."

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj : Actually I want to use phpMyAdmin only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try it after reinstalling phpmyadmin..

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are on hosting server.
Most probably you are getting a limited number of databases on your account.

You must have exceeded the allowed no. of databases on the account.

If not please add a comment, we will see again.

Cheers!!!

Comment: I was able to create it by writing sql, but when i tried to open from left bar it gives me this error "The requested URL /phpMyAdmin/db_structure.php was not found on this server.".

Answer (score -1):

Yes. I was had same problem. What i do is.. move to another browser.

Im using mozilla when i had the problem. Then when i change to using interrnet explorer. Its work perfectly. Idk, what happen but this is work...

Comment: Please ensure you read all the comments before answering. If you had it would have been clear this was an installation issue... not a browser issue.